# Is there a concurrency between runLater blocks in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, javafx

I perform a background task in a Javafx GUI application in a separate thread, which has to provide some hint to the user as to the status of this process, from time to time updating some GUI elements. In order to do this the task has to be organized in runLater blocks. Each runLater block processes an element of an array and increases the array counter which is a global variable. It seems to work, but my question is whether it is guaranteed that there is no concurrency between these runLater blocks ( which are started one after the other in a single loop ), or is it necessary to provide some mutual exclusion mechanism when accessing the array ( in the form of a mutex or queue ).

( The user notification happens in an other thread, but it only works if the working thread is split into several runLater blocks. )

```
public void do_deep()
    {

        do_deep_i=0;

        String fen=b.report_fen();

        for(int i=0;i<deep_legal_move_list_buffer_cnt;i++)
        {

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
            {

                public void run()
                {

                    deep_san=deep_legal_move_list_buffer[do_deep_i++];

                    b.set_from_fen(fen);

                    b.make_san_move(deep_san, false);

                    //System.out.println("deep san "+deep_san+" fen "+b.report_fen());

                    b.go_infinite();

                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException ex)
                    {

                    }

                    b.stop_engine();

                    b.set_from_fen(fen);

                    //System.out.println("score "+b.score_numerical);

                    record_eval(fen,deep_san,-b.score_numerical);

                }

            });

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex)
            {

            }

            if(interrupt_deep)
            {

                break;

            }

        }

        deep_going=false;

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
        {

            public void run()
            {
                start_deep_modal.close();
            }

        });

    }
```

Comment: I think this looks fine as it is; once you have initialized `do_deep_i`, you only ever reference it from a single thread (the FX Application Thread). Similarly with the array. If you are accessing that elsewhere in a different thread, you should use an [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) to wrap that value.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would write a getter/setter for do_deep_i and make them synchronized.  This will guarantee that only one thread at a time can modify the variable.

Edit:  Platform.runLater is run on the JavaFX Application thread and is not concurrent.  Any time Platform.runLater is called, the code is submitted to a queue and is run when the thread has an opportune time to run it.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-

Comment: It is not just the accessing of the array where mutual exclusion may be warranted. All runLater blocks use the same complicated object 'b' modifying its internal state, so if they were concurrent the program should crash left and right and it does not. This gave me the idea that there may be a guarantee that runLater blocks are executed on a single block at a time basis.

Comment: To my knowledge Platform.runLater is run on the Application thread, so it is not concurrent.  It just finds an opportune time to run the code.  I updated my answer to include a link to the Platform docs for runLater.